# npm doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

running `npm install` from **any** directory having `package.json` is not working for me at the moment. I've even tried it with some well known projects but the problem is same, so I guess it's not me messing up with my `package.json`.

So the problem is, `npm install` actually install about **241** modules in my local `node_modules` directory. While i have clearly listed just 3 in `package.json`. npm behaves abruptly installing the again and again, everytime I run it.

I previously worked with same code committed to git and `npm install` just resulted in *3* packages in my `node_modules`.

```
$ npm -v
3.8.1

$ node -v
v5.8.0
```

list of modules inside `node_modules`

```
$ ls node_modules/
ansi-regex        color-convert           extract-zip               gulp-concat        isstream                lodash.template          ordered-read-streams  request                supports-color
ansi-styles       combined-stream         extsprintf                gulp-util          jodid25519              lodash.templatesettings  os-homedir            resolve                throttleit
archy             commander               fancy-log                 gulplog            jsbn                    loud-rejection           parse-json            rimraf                 through2
array-differ      concat-map              fd-slicer                 har-validator      json-schema             lru-cache                path-exists           semver                 tildify
array-find-index  concat-stream           find-index                has-ansi           json-stringify-safe     map-obj                  path-is-absolute      sequencify             time-stamp
array-uniq        concat-with-sourcemaps  find-up                   has-gulplog        jsonpointer             meow                     path-type             sigmund                tough-cookie
asn1              core-util-is            findup-sync               hawk               jsprim                  mime-db                  pend                  signal-exit            trim-newlines
assert-plus       cryptiles               first-chunk-stream        hoek               liftoff                 mime-types               pify                  single-line-log        tunnel-agent
async             dashdash                flagged-respawn           home-path          load-json-file          minimatch                pinkie                sntp                   tweetnacl
aws-sign2         dateformat              forever-agent             hosted-git-info    lodash                  minimist                 pinkie-promise        source-map             typedarray
aws4              debug                   form-data                 http-signature     lodash._basecopy        mkdirp                   pretty-bytes          sparkles               unique-stream
balanced-match    decamelize              gaze                      indent-string      lodash._basetostring    ms                       pretty-hrtime         spdx-correct           user-home
beeper            deep-extend             generate-function         inflight           lodash._basevalues      multipipe                process-nextick-args  spdx-exceptions        util-deprecate
bl                defaults                generate-object-property  inherits           lodash._getnative       mv                       progress-stream       spdx-expression-parse  v8flags
boom              delayed-stream          get-stdin                 ini                lodash._isiterateecall  ncp                      pseudomap             spdx-license-ids       validate-npm-package-license
bower             deprecated              glob                      interpret          lodash._reescape        node-uuid                qs                    speedometer            verror
brace-expansion   duplexer2               glob-stream               is-arrayish        lodash._reevaluate      normalize-package-data   rc                    sshpk                  vinyl
builtin-modules   ecc-jsbn                glob-watcher              is-builtin-module  lodash._reinterpolate   nugget                   read-pkg              stream-consume         vinyl-fs
camelcase         electron-download       glob2base                 is-finite          lodash._root            number-is-nan            read-pkg-up           string_decoder         wrappy
camelcase-keys    electron-prebuilt       globule                   is-my-json-valid   lodash.escape           oauth-sign               readable-stream       stringstream           xtend
caseless          end-of-stream           glogg                     is-property        lodash.isarguments      object-assign            rechoir               strip-ansi             yallist
chalk             error-ex                graceful-fs               is-typedarray      lodash.isarray          object-keys              redent                strip-bom              yauzl
clone             escape-string-regexp    graceful-readlink         is-utf8            lodash.keys             once                     repeating             strip-indent
clone-stats       extend                  gulp                      isarray            lodash.restparam        orchestrator             replace-ext           strip-json-comments
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "./node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron --harmony --enable-transparent-visuals ."
  },
  "author": "ishankhare07@gmail.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: have done that, however i don't feel it has anything to do with this file. the files was committed to git and hasn't changed for a while. `npm` now feels like full of shit given many other people around the web are experiencing various issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour of npm has changed from version 2 to 3 and later: version 2 and older used subfolders. Since version 3 you get a flat package structure. So what you now see is all the transient dependencies that before were available as subfolders (node_modules) of your 4 dependencies.

However, the final behaviour should be exactly the same.

The rationale behind this can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

Comment: can you please elaborate `flat package`?
why is it justified to download a *shit load* of packages when all its was supposed to do was install 3?

Comment: As I hopefully explained in my answer: in the past you got the same s**t load of packages, only the were hidden in subfolders of your 3 main packages :)

Comment: If i understand you correctly, does it has anything to do with organisation of (internal / recursive) dependencies, (dependencies of dependencies) in sort of root of `node_modules` instead of organizing it as a tree?